# my basic React hello world isn't working.

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I am trying to run the html file below and i cannot understand why it wont work. I pretty sure I have all the components. The only thing that gets displayed is the "Single Page Application" h1. I cannot display the Hello world h1.

```
<html>
<head>  
    <title>Lab 5 To Do list</title>
        <!--For React -->   
        <script src="https://unpkg.com/react@15.3.2/dist/react.js"></script>
        <script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@15.3.2/dist/react-dom.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-core/5.8.23/browser.min.js"></script>


</head> 
<body>
<h1>Single Page Application</h1>
    <div id = "MyContainer"></div>
</body>
<script type = "text/Babel">

    const hello = <h1>Hello world</h1>;

    ReactDOM.render( {hello} ,      document.getElementById('MyContainer') );


</script>
</html>
```

Comment: @torresomar I have tried with and without curly braces.

Answer (score 0):

Try to implement a simple functional component:

```
const hello = props => <h1>Hello world</h1>;
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a few problems with your code. For one thing,

```
const hello = <h1>Hello world</h1>;
```

is not a valid React component. Components are case sensitive (`Hello`), and for this case, must be designed as a function.

Additionally, when you are calling `ReactDOM.render()`, you need to treat your component as if it were an html element, i.e. `<Hello />`.

This code is correct:

```
<html>
    <head>  
    <title>Lab 5 To Do list</title>

    <!--For React -->   
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/react@15.3.2/dist/react.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@15.3.2/dist/react-dom.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-core/5.8.23/browser.min.js"></script>

    </head> 

    <body>
        <h1>Single Page Application</h1>
        <div id = "MyContainer"></div>
    </body>

    <script type = "text/babel">

        const Hello = props => (
            <h1>Hello world</h1>
        );

        ReactDOM.render( 
            <Hello />,      
            document.getElementById('MyContainer') 
        );

    </script>
</html>
```

You should check out the tutorial on the [React homepage](https://reactjs.org/tutorial/tutorial.html), it is very helpful.